# Selenium Python Iterate Through Web Table Columns, Stop after condition is True, Throw Error if Condition is False

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, assert

I am trying to validate whether or not data values (which include dollars and cents amounts) are being populated in certain columns of an HTML table. I have written a Selenium Python Script that uses a For Loop to iterate through the HTML table. I have added an IF / ELSE in the For Loop to check if a decimal point is found in any of the text in the columns on the table. If a values with a decimal point is found, then variable "values_filled" is set to True (if not, then "values_filled" is set to False). My thinking is that if a value with a decimal point is found, then the column is being populated successfully with dollars and cents values. If no decimal point is found, then the column is NOT being populated and this should trigger a "FAIL".

The code that I have written successfully iterates through the rows and columns of the HTML table. Further, the IF / ELSE section is correctly flagging "values_filled" = True if there is a value with a decimal point and values_filled = False if no values found. Last, I have a TRY / EXCEPT section where an exception is thrown if the values_filled is "False".

What I would like to do next is when the first instance of the "values_filled" = True is found, I want to end the loop. However, the loop continues even when the values_filled value is true.

```
account_balances_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/ui-view/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/table")
rows = account_balances_table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for col in cols:
        text_found = cols[1].text
        if ("." in text_found):
            values_filled = True
            if values_filled == True:
                break
            else:
                continue
        else:
            values_filled = False

        try:
            assert values_filled is True
        except AssertionError:
            screenshot_name = "FAIL" + "_" + test_case_ID + "_" + browser + "_" + env + "_" + time_stamp + ".png"
            saved_screenshot_location = str(screenshot_directory / screenshot_name)
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file(saved_screenshot_location)
            raise
```

The problem I am encountering is that the For Loop continues even when values_filled is "true". I inserted a break but the loop does not stop. This is a problem as the script continues and falsely flags an exception for blank values found in other cells. I would like the loop to end after finding the first instance of values_filled = true.

Comment: Update: I found a solution. I moved the values_filled variable above the for loop. Next, I removed the second IF statement, and the continue and else lines. Code is now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a solution that works.

```
account_balances_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/ui-view/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/table")
rows = account_balances_table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
values_filled = False
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for col in cols:
        text_found = cols[1].text
        if ("." in text_found):
            values_filled = True
            break

        try:
            assert values_filled is True
        except AssertionError:
            screenshot_name = "FAIL" + "_" + test_case_ID + "_" + browser + "_" + env + "_" + time_stamp + ".png"
            saved_screenshot_location = str(screenshot_directory / screenshot_name)
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file(saved_screenshot_location)
            raise
```